# close and exit from my App in android

Tags: android

I have an application where on the home page I have buttons for navigation through the application.

On that page I have a button "EXIT" which when clicked should take the user to the home screen on the phone where the application icon is.

But its go me to home screen but radio still work.

How can I do that?

my code id :-

```
//method for exit.
public void exitradio() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Edit :-

i will try this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
            if(v == PlayBtn){
                 startradio();
              }
             else if(v == PauseBtn){
                 pauseradio();
              }
             else if(v == ExitBtn){
                 exitradio();
              }
             else if(v == RefreshBtn){
                 try {
                    refreshradio();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            }
```

and the `exitradio();` code is :-

```
//method for exit.
public void exitradio() {
    //finish();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

and still close app but radio still work

---

my MainActivity class is :-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
        // Define ..............................................................
        private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        public MediaPlayer mp;
        boolean isPrepared = false;
        Button PlayBtn , ExitBtn , PauseBtn , RefreshBtn;
        String MEDIA_PATH;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Buffering Radio...",true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // Declare ..............................................................
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        PlayBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        PlayBtn .setOnClickListener(this);
        PauseBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
        PauseBtn .setOnClickListener(this);
        RefreshBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRefresh);
        RefreshBtn .setOnClickListener(this);
        ExitBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
        ExitBtn .setOnClickListener(this);
        MEDIA_PATH = "http://radio.arabhosters.com:8015/"; 

        // Volume Control ..............................................................
        final AudioManager leftAm = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int maxVolume = leftAm.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        int curVolume = leftAm.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        SeekBar volControl = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volumebar);
        volControl.setMax(maxVolume);
        volControl.setProgress(curVolume);
        volControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             leftAm.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, arg1, 0);
            }
           });  
    }


@Override
public void onClick(View v){
            if(v == PlayBtn){
                 startradio();
              }
             else if(v == PauseBtn){
                 pauseradio();
              }
             else if(v == ExitBtn){
                 exitradio();
              }
             else if(v == RefreshBtn){
                 try {
                    refreshradio();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            }

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
         synchronized(this){
            isPrepared = false;
            }
            }

protected void onResume (){
        super.onResume();

        try {
            mp.setDataSource(MEDIA_PATH);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } //also consider mp.prepareAsync().
        // defult start stream when start App.  
        mp.start();
        mp.setVolume(100, 100);
        progressDialog.dismiss();        
        }

        // method for play stream after stop it.
public void startradio() {
            try{
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                    return;
                }  
                   mp.start();
                   progressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch(IllegalStateException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }

// method for Refresh stream.
public void refreshradio() throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IOException {
        try{
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                return;
            }
               mp.reset();
               mp.setDataSource(MEDIA_PATH);
               mp.prepare(); 
               mp.start();
               progressDialog.dismiss(); 
        } catch(IllegalStateException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

// method for pause stream. 
public void pauseradio() {
        mp.pause();
    }

// method for check is radio paly or not stream
public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mp.isPlaying();
    }

// method for Looping audio if your record it - Soon :)
public boolean isLooping() {
        return mp.isLooping();
    }

// method for Looping audio if your record it - Soon :)
public void setLooping(boolean isLooping) {
        mp.setLooping(isLooping);
    }

// method for volume
public void setVolume(float volumeLeft, float volumeRight) {
        mp.setVolume(volumeLeft, volumeRight);
    }

// method for stop stream.
public void stopradio() {
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.stop();
        }
        mp.release();
    }

//method for exit.
public void exitradio() {
    //finish();
    System.exit(0);
}

//method for back to main menu "Home".
public void backtomenu() {
  finish();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

and StartPoint class like :-

```
public class StartPoint extends Activity{

ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressBarStatus = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);


    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
                while(progressBarStatus < 5000){
                    StartPoint.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run()
                        {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                            progressBarStatus += 1000;
                        }
                    });

                }
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openMainList = new Intent(StartPoint.this, com.example.kam.MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(openMainList);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

}
```

Comment: what radio are you talking about? Also, why introduce confusing UI elements? Android has a perfectly good "HOME" button. You're not doing anyone any favors by giving them an extra home button. You're just cluttering up your UI.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel how can i cluttering up my UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set listener on your exit Button (

> in  my example is : btn_exit

)
your app will exit at all :)

```
    public class testprj extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn_exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn_exit .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    }
 }
```

**

> also make sure that the first activity is finished (onStop() ==> make
>   finish() )

**

Comment: thank you, i don't see **also make sure that the first activity is finished (onStop() ==> make finish() )** now its work good thank you

Comment: can you come here :)

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310916/why-display-black-background-between-two-layouts)